# OpenGL in a second thread, which is started in a class

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl

I have a Window class which creates a OpenGL Window and starts the rendering loop. If I create a Window in a thread in main, it works.

```
void threadTest() {  
    Window w(800, 600, "Hallo Welt");  
}

int main() {
    std::thread t(threadTest);
    sleep(5);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

However, if I create the thread in my Engine class, it segfaults.

```
void Engine::createWindow(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, const std::string & title) {
    m_rendering = new std::thread(&Engine::windowThread, * this, width, height, title);
}

void Engine::windowThread(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, const std::string & title) {
    Window w(width, height, title);
}

int main() {
    Engine e;
    e.createWindow(800, 600, "Hallo Welt");
    sleep(5);
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In which thread does your message loop run?

Comment: Never mind, I didn't look closely enough at your main function, sorry.

Comment: I added how main looks like with my Engine class.

Comment: Since you are discussing threads here, you are aware that GL commands can only be issued from a thread that has an active GL context, correct? And that a context can only be active in **0** or **1** threads at a time. If you ever tried to issue commands from a different thread than the one that created your context, and you do not understand this then confusing run-time behvior would ensue; multi-threading is fine in GL, but you have to mind which threads have active contexts.

Comment: Yes, I know this. I only intend to use one thread for all of the GL stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making your thread function static.

ie:

```
 static void Engine::windowThread(
     unsigned int width, 
     unsigned int height, 
     const std::string & title) 
 {

     Window w(width, height, title);
 }
```

If you need to pass the class instance, then use an extra param for the this pointer.

Comment: Yep, removing the this parameter and making the function static worked. Thanks a lot!